# ios checking for an empty object

Tags: ios, error-handling, nserror

I have an error getting passed by reference to some code I found online. The error comes back as an empty object meaning there was no error.

if I check for `error.code` I get a *bad access* because the object is empty.

if I check for `error == nil` I get a *false* because `error` is an empty object.

How can I use logic to find that the error exists, but is empty?

Comment: You are misdiagnosing the problem.  There's no such thing as "an empty object".  I suspect you aren't checking for success correctly and are dereferencing a dangling pointer.  Post the code that you are using and perhaps somebody will be able to help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Errors are usually of type `NSError` or a subclass of it. They are passed as references in methods declared this way:

```
-(void)DoSomeStuff:(NSError **)error;
```

So, when you call a method that requires you to pass a reference to a `NSError` you call it this way:

```
NSError *error = nil;
[self DoSomeStuff:&error];
```

When this method finished its work you check if the error object has actually filled with something:

```
if(error)
{
   //Do some stuff if there is an error.
   //To see the human readable description you can:
   NSLog(@"The error was: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
   //To see the error code you do:
   NSLog(@"The error code: %d", error.code);
}
else //There is no error you proceed as normal
{
  //Do some other stuff - no error
}
```

P.S. If you get no error and the method does not behave as expected then there is something wrong with the implementation with this method. Especially if it's an open source stuff, coding mistakes can easily appear, so you can take a look at what the method does, debug and even fix if something is wrong...

Comment: `if(error)` is not the way most Apple APIs are designed.  Most Apple APIs return a `BOOL` to indicate whether an error has occurred.  There is no guarantee that the error pointer will be `nil` upon success.

Comment: Interesting, have you caught such case - success, but the error is initialized and the opposite? What does Apple suggests about async methods for ex. `-(void)DoSomeStuffAsync:(void(^)(NSError *error))completionBlock`, where  i can see for example that my async method has failed at some point?

Comment: I haven't caught one personally because I follow the API and check return values instead.  [There's more details on this mistake here](http://rentzsch.tumblr.com/post/260201639/nserror-is-hard), including links to official documentation.

Comment: Async stuff wouldn't seem to be a problem unless it was multithreaded, in which case use `@synchronized` like any other multithreaded code.